# Are all the elements of a map $A \stackrel {\delta} \rightarrow A$ symmetric or they're only symmetric when it's clear that it's an identity map?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm reading Jacobson's *Basic Algebra*:

> For any set $S$ one defines the *identity* map $1_S$ as $S \stackrel {1_S} \rightarrow S$ where $1_S$ is the subset of elements $(s,s)$ of $S \times S$.

I have a doubt, if the identity map is the subset of elements $(s,s)$, it means that this subset would have elements like $(1,1), (2,2), (3,3),\cdots$ - But this happens only when clearly specificated that this map is the identity map, right? I mean, supose we have:

$$\mathbb{N} \stackrel {\delta} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$$

**Where it's not clear that it's an identity map**, we would have elements like $(1,2)$, $(1,5),\cdots$ right?

I guess I could ask it like this: Are all the elements of a map $A \stackrel {\delta} \rightarrow A$ symmetric or only when it's clearly stated that it is an identity map?

Sorry for the poorly written question, I'm a little confused.

Comment: Do you understand why a map $S\to S$ can be regarded as a subset of $S\times S$?

Comment: @Florian Yes. A map assigns elements of one set to elements in the other set. What I'm not sure is if this map has only symmetric subsets. (Not sure I answered your question satisfactorily, though).